# looping through folders while performing task

Tags: r, for-loop, directory, shapefile, listdir

I'm trying to loop through folders in a directory while reading and assigning files to variables in `R`.

The files I want to assign to variables are `shapefiles` so I use the function `readOGR` from the `rgdal` package. The purpose is to later merge all shapefiles belonging to a particular species. The hierarchy/structure of the directory is `type1` > `species` > `ids`. The `shapefiles` look like `id.shp` etc.

Example shapefiles can be downloaded [here](http://www.marineregions.org/gazetteer.php?p=details&id=1905) and [here](http://www.marineregions.org/gazetteer.php?p=details&id=4279)

```
#code
setwd("~/type1/")

#Extract ids belonging to $species. Later use in readOCR function

sp_id <- function(species){
 wd = "~/type1/"
 list_shp <- list.files(path=paste(wd,species,sep='/'), full.names = F, recursive = F, include.dirs = F)
 vec <- character() 

  for (shp in list_shp){
   y <- unlist(strsplit(shp, '\\.', perl=T))
   vec <- unique(c(vec,y[1]))
  }

 #"1905" "4279"

#Extract dirs for where to perform readOCR function

  list_dir <- list.dirs(path=paste(wd,species,sep='/'), full.names = F, recursive = F)

   for (id in list_dir){
    setwd(id)
    print(getwd())
   }

#"~/type1/speciesX1/1905"
#"~/type1/speciesX1/4279"

    for (i in vec){
     assign(paste("", i, sep=""), readOGR(".", i))
    break
    }
 }

sp_id('speciesX1')

[1] "~/type1/speciesX1/1905"
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: ".", layer: "1905"
with 10 features and 3 fields
Feature type: wkbPolygon with 2 dimensions
[1] "~/type1/speciesX1/4279"
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv) : 
Cannot open layer
```

The problem is that the code only executes `readOGR` for one `shapefile` in one of the `dirs`,  seems to change dir again but doesn't execute the last `readOGR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function seems to be broken in many different sections, but you could just do:

```
library(rgdal)

setwd("~/type1/")
species <- 'speciesX1'
list_shp <- list.files(path=species, pattern="*.shp", full.names = TRUE,
                       recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = FALSE)
shp_objects <- lapply(list_shp, function(x) {readOGR(dsn=x, 
                                                     layer=ogrListLayers(x))})
```

This will give you a list of `SpatialPolygonDataframe` objects that you can then merge.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Have to remember to use the `apply` functions more often. Just for the case of learning, can you tell me where my function is broken?

Comment: 1. Your function name `sp_id` is different to what you are calling later (`sp_mrgid('speciesX1')`)  
2. `setwd(id)` on line 25 will cause an error (as far as I saw it, you never set the wd to `species` which subfolders you're trying to access

These were just quick observation, didn't try to debug it in earnest.

Comment: Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jlehtoma/7924643) demonstrating the merge.

Comment: Cheers for commenting and for the merge demonstration. Ah, yeah, the name is only a typo when writing the thread. I tend to change names from the code which has its apparent disadvantages. The other thing you mention is not an error if Im correct. `list_dir <- list.dirs(path=paste(wd,species,sep='/'), full.names = F, recursive = F)` where `species` (function argument) is the subfolder. This works in the code as I've indicated...

Answer (score 0):

I could not get `ogrInfo()` to read those files getting a missing layer error). This provided a method to read and get some of the attributes. (A Mac will take duplicate names of directories and append "(n)" to them, so the identically named but different files were iho.zip and iho.zip:

```
library(sp)

ca3 = readShapeSpatial("~/Downloads/iho/iho.shp")
ca3 = readShapeSpatial("~/Downloads/iho(2)/iho.shp")

> attributes(ca3)$data
                               name   id mrgid
0 Mediterranean Sea - Western Basin 28Aa  4279
1               Strait of Gibraltar  28a  3346
2                       Alboran Sea  28b  3324
3                      Balearic Sea  28c  3322
4                      Ligurian Sea  28d  3363
5                    Tyrrhenian Sea  28e  3386
> attributes(ca2)$data
                               name   id mrgid
0 Mediterranean Sea - Western Basin 28Aa  4279
1 Mediterranean Sea - Eastern Basin 28Bb  4280
2               Strait of Gibraltar  28a  3346
3                       Alboran Sea  28b  3324
4                      Balearic Sea  28c  3322
5                      Ligurian Sea  28d  3363
6                    Tyrrhenian Sea  28e  3386
7                      Adriatic Sea  28g  3314
8                        Ionian Sea  28f  3351
9                        Aegean Sea  28h  3315
```

Comment: Cheers for commenting. Could you maybe explain how this can help my above problem?

Comment: Well, I'm agreeing that there may be a problem with your source of shp files. Hard to tell what your error really is. I got the sense these were not your real files and that you had not produced a reproducible example. If these are the actual files you are using rather than easily available ones for illustration, and no one comes along with a better approach, then perhaps you can go to the R-SIG-GEO mailing list.

Comment: Ah, ok. I got `ogrInfo()` to work though... e.g. `ogrInfo(".", "1905")` (renamed to match mrgid)

Comment: I would think that the problem lies in my function per se. I think I need `next` or `break` to restart the loop(?)